# How to create custom header in soap request with Java?

Tags: soap, axis

I'm trying to add Header information to soap request. But, Header tag is not be generated what i want. Body information is right. When i set SOAPHeaderElement to Stub, Header is populated but, results are wrong. There is mistaken part in Header tag.

I' m working with Apache Axis and my code is running on the client site. I tried to manipulate the Header tag, but i could not.

```java
SOAPHeaderElement header0 = new SOAPHeaderElement(new QName("OMIHeader", "UserID"), "admin");
      SOAPHeaderElement header1 = new SOAPHeaderElement(new QName("OMIHeader", "sessionID"), sessionID);
      header0.setActor(null);
      header1.setActor(null);
      stub.setHeader(header1);
      stub.setHeader(header0);
```

my Expectation is to see

```xml
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:UserID xmlns:ns1="OMIHeader" > <ns1:UserID>
    <ns1:SessionID xmlns:ns1="OMIHeader"> </ns1:SessionID>
</soapenv:Header>
```

result is

```xml
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:sessionID xmlns:ns1="OMIHeader" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" href="#id0"/>
    <ns2:UserID xmlns:ns2="OMIHeader" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="soapenc:string">admin</ns2:UserID>
  </soapenv:Header>

 <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:long">5933586835133012953</multiRef>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's a problem. First question: What is the value of `sessionID` in your code?  Second, have you tried sending that to a service and seen an error?  SOAP generally, and AXIS specifically are noisy and add lots of stuff that seems superfluous, but still works.  Cleaning up the output to a minimal package is probably a bigger job than you want.

Comment: Actually, I tried to send the request to server and Server response was invalid SessionID. I get the SessionID from Server while logging in then i have to add it to Header of following request. I think problem is caused by 'xmlns:soapenc' attribute